# MongoDB Embed same object

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a Product Collection and would like to embed Image like this
FYI, I am using Morphia framework.
Do you foresee any problem embedding image twice like this?

Or should i make image reference?

```
@Embedded
public ArrayList<Image> MainImages
public ArrayList<Image> SecondaryImages
```

Answer (score 0):

You might run into some issues embedding the images into the products documents. Consider:

- the document size limit of 16 MB
- overhead of moving a big document around during an update
- can not share images of similar products

I suggest to use the `GridFS` file system of MongoDB to store the images. The GridFS consisits of two collections:

- chunks: stores the binary data (images, in your case) in chunks of, by default, 256k
- files: stores the indexes and metadata

GridFS can be sharded, possibly only the chunks collection

You could consider a "mixed mode" between embedding and using GridFS: embedding thumbnail images for fast delivery and storing the bigger images on GridFS.

For more information on GridFS, refer to the [general description](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/gridfs/), the [operations reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) and [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-gridfs-data/).